# R - Remove Column From Printout

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

I build a dataframe with a loop and rbind (which I think is why this problem comes up).  Then when I print out the data frame it looks like this

```
           edge, my_f_price, book_f_price, my_d_price, book_d_price
1:1    9.8973782   113.8974         -112  -113.8974         -104
1:11  -1.1026218   113.8974         -105  -113.8974         -115
1:12  -7.6656557  -147.6657         -160   147.6657          140
1:13   1.9645988   107.9646         -110  -107.9646         -106
```

How do I remove the first column (1:1, 1:11, 1:12, 1:13), which isn't a true column, from the printout? I need to print this out to a txt file and that column is not wanted.

Comment: yeah i agree its a duplicate.  ill mark the below answer as accepted though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
write.table(dd, file="output.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

**?Write.table** should help you

Comment: for some reason that output came out bad.  i put it as write.csv(...) and it worked.